# how to use multiple <input type="image"> in a HTML form?

Tags: html, forms, input

I would like to have a form with mutliple input but without using an `<input type=submit>` or a `<button>`. (because buttons are not supported by IE and `<input type="submit">` display the text value and I want an image instead of text inside the button ). The problem is that that form send "null" value  instead of `value="${CdFile.path}"`
thanks you for your help!

```html
<form action="depending of the input choosen" method="post" id="ContactForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <table id="table_id" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="1" align="left" bgcolor="#999999">
  <caption> Files of current user</caption>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th>Download</th>
        <!--th>Directory</th-->
        <th>file Name</th>
        <th>document type</th>
        <th>Date</th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="image" width="50" name="subject" src=" http://res.cloudinary.com/virbac/image/upload/v1471939749/download_smaflx.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="${CdFile.path}" />
        </td>
        <!--td>${CdFile.folder}</td-->
        <td>${CdFile.fileName}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.docType}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.date}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="image" width="50" name="subject" src=" http://res.cloudinary.com/virbac/image/upload/v1471939749/download_smaflx.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="${CdFile.path}" />
        </td>
        <!--td>${CdFile.folder}</td-->
        <td>${CdFile.fileName}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.docType}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.date}</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <input type="image" width="50" name="subject" src=" http://res.cloudinary.com/virbac/image/upload/v1471939749/download_smaflx.png" border="0" alt="Submit" value="${CdFile.path}" />
        </td>
        <!--td>${CdFile.folder}</td-->
        <td>${CdFile.fileName}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.docType}</td>
        <td>${CdFile.date}</td>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
   </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you be some more clear about your problem

Comment: Yes of course, I have some files on a server and i want to make them downloadable, my form actually works with traditionnal input, the value of the input are the path to the file. But this value is displayed in the button and I want an image instead of the text displayed

Comment: So when the click on the `input[submit]` the file should download. or else is it okay to open it in new tab to view image

Comment: Yes when there is a click on the input the file should be downloaded but the problem is that the  <input type=image> send null value instead of the path

Comment: Try this once `<a href="IMAGE_LINK" download>IMAGE_TEXT</a>`

Comment: _“because buttons are not supported by IE”_ – that’s nonsense. There have been problems with the wrong value being submitted in IE7, but that was fixed in IE8. So unless you have to specifically cater to users using these massively outdated browsers, that whole argument is void. So use buttons, instead of trying to work around a problem which doesn’t even exist in actual reality …

Comment: I finally found a solution , I've put a form for every button with an hidden input.

Answer (score 0):

You can't add an image inside a button, but you can embed an image within a hyperlink tag like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/data.zip">
    <img src="/image.jpg" alt="download">
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks you but I can't reach the file with an hyperlink, I use socket technology to stream the selected file

Comment: Its not button.its hyperlink

Comment: Then what does it means? :) "This will convert a image into button"

Comment: @ArunjithRS - my bad :(

Comment: @SanjayAchar anyway nice Answer :)